# Comparison of Solutions to SDEs

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $B(t)$ be a Brownian motion. If we assume that $b(t, x), b_i(t, x)$, $\sigma(t, x)$, and $\sigma_i(t, x)$ are Lipschitz functions for $i = 1, 2$ then it is known that if $X_i(t)$ is the unique solution to
$$
dX_i(t) = b_i(t, X_i(t)) dt + \sigma(t, X_i(t)) dB(t)
$$
with $X_1(0) = X_2(0) = x_0$ and $b_1(t, x) \leq b_2(t, x)$, then $X_1(t) \leq X_2(t)$ almost surely. The intuition with this case is that $X_2(t)$ always moves at least as much 'upwards' as $X_1(t)$ will.

I'm looking to consider the case where diffusion terms are different instead. The inequality we expect will not be quite as simple. My question is: If $Z(t)$ uniquely solves
$$
dZ(t) = b(t,Z(t)) dt + \sigma(t, Z(t)) dB(t)
$$
and for $i = 1,2$ the process $Z_i(t)$ unique solves
$$
dZ_i(t) = b(t,Z_i(t)) dt + \sigma_i(t, Z_i(t)) dB(t)
$$
with $Z(0) = Z_1(0) = Z_2(0) = z_0$ and $\sigma_1(t, x) \leq \sigma(t, x) \leq \sigma_2(t, x)$, then is it true that
$$
|Z(t)| \leq \max (|Z_1(t)|, |Z_2(t)|)?
$$

The intuition behind this statement is that, if the direction of movement caused by Brownian motion is upward (or downward), the process $Z(t)$ should be bounded by a process with stronger (or weaker) diffusion term, namely $Z_2(t)$ (or $Z_1(t)$).

Comment: I'm guessing you probably want something like $0 < c \le \sigma_1(t,x)$ for some constant $c$ too, because the solutions to SDEs can get weird if the diffusion term approaches $0$.

Comment: @user6247850 This is true. If a result like this can be shown with even some restrictive assumptions that would be great, I'm just not sure what is the best way to approach this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a relatively simple counter example. Let $\sigma<\mu$ be constant diffusion coefficients and consider the two SDEs

\begin{align}
dZ_t&=\sigma Z_t\,dB_t\,,&dY_t&=\mu Y_t\,dB_t\,,
\end{align}
with initial conditions $Z_0=Y_0=1\,.$
Their explicit solutions are the two GBMs
\begin{align}
Z_t&=\exp(\sigma B_t-\sigma^2t/2)\,,&Y_t&=\exp(\mu B_t-\mu^2t/2)\,.
\end{align}
For these, the conjecture
$$\tag{1}
|Z_t|\le |Y_t|\quad{ a.s. }
$$
is equivalent to
$$\tag{2}
\frac{Z_t}{Y_t}\le 1\quad{ a.s. }
$$
But this cannot be true. Proof:
$$
\frac{Z_t}{Y_t}=\exp\Big(\sigma B_t-\mu B_t-\sigma^2t/2+\mu^2t/2\Big)\,.
$$
Therefore,
$$\tag{3}
\mathbb E\Big[\frac{Z_t}{Y_t}\Big]=\exp(-\sigma\mu t+\mu^2t)\,.
$$
It is easy to see that since $\sigma<\mu$ the right hand side is strictly greater  than one.
Therefore (2) cannot hold.

Let
$$
dX_t=\nu X_t\,dB_t\,,\quad \nu<\sigma\,,X_0=1\,.
$$
In this notation your conjecture reads
$$
Z_t\le \max(X_t,Y_t)\quad\text{ a.s. }\,.
$$
To refute this I will show now that with positive probability
$$\tag{4}
X_t<Y_t<Z_t
$$
holds. Proof.
\begin{align}
\mathbb P\Big\{\frac{Y_t}{X_t}\le 1\Big\}&=\mathbb P\Big\{\exp\big(\mu B_t-\nu B_t-\mu^2t/2+\nu^2t/2\big)\le 1\Big\}\\
&=\Phi\Bigg(\frac{\mu^2 t-\nu^2t}{2\sqrt{\mu^2t+\nu^2t-2\mu\nu t}}\Bigg)\\
&=\Phi\Big(\frac{\mu+\nu}{2}\sqrt{t}\Big)\,,\tag{5}
\end{align}
and similarly,
\begin{align}
\mathbb P\Big\{\frac{Z_t}{Y_t}\le 1\Big\}
&=\Phi\Bigg(\frac{\sigma^2 t-\mu^2t}{2\sqrt{\sigma^2t+\mu^2t-2\sigma\mu t}}\Bigg)\\
&=\Phi\Big(-\frac{\sigma+\mu}{2}\sqrt{t}\Big)\,.\tag{6}
\end{align}
The minus sign here comes from $\sigma<\mu\,.$

For example, when $t=1,\nu=0.01,\sigma=0.1,\mu=0.11$ the sum of these
probabilities (5) and (6) is strictly less than one.

Then however
$$
\mathbb P\Big(\big\{X_t<Y_t\big\}\cap\big\{Y_t<Z_t\big\}\Big)>0\,.
$$

Comment: Thanks for shedding some light onto the problem. If we had $dX_t = \nu X_t dB_t$ also with $\nu < \sigma$, then wouldn't $\mathbb{E}(Z_t/X_t) < 1$? So while we have $|Z_t| \leq |Y_t|$ almost surely, this is not clear for $|Z_t| \leq |X_t|$. Please let me know if I am confusing myself here.

Comment: Yes. With the same method you can show that $\mathbb E[Z_t/X_t]<1\,.$ You can however not conclude from this that $Z_t<X_t$ a.s.  I am a bit confused about your sentence "So while we have $|Z_t|≤|Y_t|$ almost surely ..." This is exactly what I showed to be *false*.

Comment: In fact, the truth of $\mathbb E[Z_t/X_t]<1$ shows in a totally symmetric fashion that the conjecture $X_t\le Z_t$ a.s. is false as well.